# Struts 2 Execute action instead of welcome file

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-action

I'm working on a Struts 2 application and I want to execute an action (in fact I'm interested more on executing an interceptor) instead of simply showing a welcome file. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Either redirect to the action from the welcome file, or use the action URL as a welcome file entry.

To do the latter, you'll likely need to set dispatcher elements on the  element:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    etc.
```

Add FORWARD, INCLUDE, and ERROR as well, and the normal filter name/url.

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit with that second option using web.xml? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two well defined option both have been mentioned by Dave in his post.he has already described the Dispatcher option and other is to use redirection something like

```
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=example/MyAction.action">
</head>
```